# Is there a way to download a selected row from a jtable?

Tags: java, mysql, download

I want to be able to select a row from jtable and download it to a .txt file. Not the entire databse just selected row. is this possible?

Currently what I'm doing is Selecting rows and transferring them to a separate jtable and then downloading from there using this code to transfer.

```
DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel) Shortlist_Table.getModel();
            int[] indexs = Shortlist_Table.getSelectedRows();
            Object[] row = new Object[3];
            DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) Final_Table.getModel();
            for(int i=0; i<indexs.length; i++)
        {
            row[0] = model1.getValueAt(indexs[i], 0);
            row[1] = model1.getValueAt(indexs[i], 1);
            row[2] = model1.getValueAt(indexs[i], 2);
            model2.addRow(row);
        }
```

Then using this code to download to a .txt file.

```
private void jButtonExportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\omar\\Desktop\\myfolder\\txtfile.txt";
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            for(int i = 0; i < jTableExport.getRowCount(); i++){//rows
                for(int j = 0; j < jTableExport.getColumnCount(); j++){//columns
                    bw.write(jTableExport.getValueAt(i, j).toString()+" ");
                }
                bw.newLine();
            }

            bw.close();
            fw.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JTable_import_and_export_to_text_file.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

But I want to be more efficient and can't find anywhere online that shows how to download selected row to the file directly. Any help appreciated, Thanks!

Edit2:
I've been trying to come up with something and so far I have this:

```
try{
           File file = new File("/Users/lucacassin/NetBeansProjects/Recruitment\\ Project/HiredCandidatesTextFile.txt");
           if(!file.exists()){
               file.createNewFile();
           }

               try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile()); BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {

                   int row = Shortlist_Table.getSelectedRow();
                   bw.write(Shortlist_Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0)+" ");
                   bw.write(Shortlist_Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1)+" ");
                   bw.write(Shortlist_Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2)+" ");
                   bw.write("\n_________\n");


               }
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Exported");

           }catch(HeadlessException | IOException ex){
           }
```

However, it's not doing anything and I don't know whats wrong as no errors thrown up or anything, just nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify and tell the details of your question and your problem, including showing pertinent code, showing what you've researched (specifically), what you've tried, what is or isn't working. In other words, please try to [edit] and improve your question so that it is both easier to answer and helpful to future visitors with similar problems as per the [help] and the [ask].

Comment: But to answer your direct question, "is this possible?", the answer is definitely, "yes", but the details all depend on things that we don't know  yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it if anyone else needs it. Similar to my edit above but I put the full file path in where I should have just put part the file name. This can now be run multiple times without overwriting the file.

```
           try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("HiredCandidatesTextFile.txt",true); BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {

                   int row = Shortlist_Table.getSelectedRow();
                   bw.write(Shortlist_Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0)+" ");
                   bw.write(Shortlist_Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1)+" ");
                   bw.write(Shortlist_Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2)+" ");
                   bw.write("\n_________\n");


               } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddShortlist.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Exported");
```